# Limitar dígitos en un número periódico en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hoy he empezado a usar python y me pregunto...
Si pongo un `print(10/3)` se limita la respuesta a

> 3.3333333333333335

porque óbviamente no podría escribir un número infinito... Pero, ¿hay algún modo de cambiar el número de cifras que escribe?
Por ejemplo, que en vez de escribir 16 cifras decimales escriba 20, o 3, o 45 (que pueda regular yo el número de cifras, en conclusión)

Comment: Tienes ya varias respuestas, pero, no olvides los problemas asociados a lo números de coma flotante, Matemáticamente hablando `10/3` no es `3.3333333333333335`, mostrarlo con tanta precisión puede confundir.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

El problema no es tanto con cuántos decimales quieres mostrar el número (que puedes controlarlo con cadenas de formato, como `"{:.10f}".format(10/3)` por ejemplo, como con qué precisión está realmente almacenado.

Por defecto los números de tipo "float" están almacenados en un formato llamado IEEE-754, el cual usa 32 o 64 bits (según la precisión sea simple o doble) para almacenar cualquier número real. Python usa la precisión doble. Naturalmente, en 64 bits que es la mayor precisión posible, se pueden representar un máximo de 2^64 números diferentes, que está muy lejos del infinito de orden Aleph1 que son los números reales. Es decir, hay infinitos números no representables en este formato.

Cuando se trabaja con números muy pequeños (del tipo 0.0000000...01) se tiene una precisión muy alta, pues los números cuya parte entera es cero se representan de una forma especial en ese formato, pudiendo llegar al orden de 2^(−1074 ), es decir, correcto hasta el decimal 324, pero a medida que los números son mayores, la precisión baja, pues el número de bits disponible para representar las cifras es constante, independientemente de dónde esté la coma.

Así, para los del tipo 1.00000...01 (que ya no tiene parte entera cero) sólo se almacena correctamente hasta el decimal 16 aproximadamente y a medida que la parte entera aumenta de tamaño, la cantidad de decimales exactos que se tiene en la parte fracción va menguando.

El resultado de 10/3 se almacena correctamente sólo hasta el decimal 15 y a partir de él ya está mal, como puedes comprobar si intentas mostrarlo con 20 decimales:

```
>>> print("{:.20f}".format(10/3))
3.33333333333333348136
```

En muchos ámbitos científicos la precisión proporcionada por el tipo `float` de Python (equivalente al `double` del C) es suficiente, ya que es habitual también en ciencia que se quiera mucha precisión al trabajar con números pequeños, y se pueda tolerar un error mayor al trabajar con números grandes, de modo que el error relativo sea constante.

No obstante, si quisieras tener control absoluto sobre la precisión, deberías dejar de usar el tipo `float` y pasar a usar el `Decimal`. En este tipo se tiene precisión arbitraria, fijada por el programador. Por desgracia es más farragoso para operar. Mira, por ejemplo, como calcular 10/3 con precisión de 30 decimales correctos:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>> getcontext().prec = 30
>>> r = Decimal(10)/Decimal(3)
>>> print(r)
3.33333333333333333333333333333
```

Aunque con `format` puedes reducir la cantidad de decimales mostrados, si tratas de aumentarlo por encima de 30 en este caso se descubre el error:

```
>>> print("{:.10f}".format(r))
3.3333333333
>>> print("{:.35f}".format(r))
3.33333333333333333333333333333000000
```

Finalmente comentar que también tienes el tipo fracción, que no intenta realizar la división sino que almacena por separado numerador y denominador, lo que evita errores de redondeo mientras trabajes con fracciones (pero aparecerán de nuevo al tratar de convertir el resultado en `float`)

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> f = Fraction(10,3)
>>> print(f)
10/3
>>> print(float(f))
3.3333333333333335
```

Answer (score 7):

Podrias hacer lo siguiente:

Declaras una variable y dentro de ella pones la division:

```
division = 10/3
```

Luego la llamas y la formateas

```
print ("{0:.5f}".format(division))
```

En esta parte le estas diciendo que tome hasta 5 decimales {0:.5f}

El resultado es:

3.33333

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cambias a 2 el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: bien... pero cuando hago print ("{0:.55f}".format(division)) empieza a dar numeros erroneos... alguna solucion??

Comment: Verifica por favor la respuesta que dejo @abulafia mas arriba, esa respuesta es mas acertada, al igual que vos soy nuevo en Python por lo que yo te pase sirve hasta unos 30 caracteres (Cosa que no sabia, leyendo la respuesta que te pido que veas me di cuenta de eso). En este caso esa respuesta es la mejor a tu pregunta por lo que tendrias que darle el punto a el  :)

Answer (score 5):

Si lo que quieres es imprimir el dato con una cantidad de decimales concreta, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
division_con_decimales = 10/3
print("{0:.2f}".format(division_con_decimales))
```

**Resultado**

```
3.33
```

Ten en cuenta que el valor no se ha modificado, `division_con_decimales` sigue teniendo los decimales que tenia antes.
Si lo que quieres es redondear a unos decimales concretos, puedes hacer:

```
menos_decimales = round(division_con_decimales, 2)
print(menos_decimales)
```

**Resultado**

```
3.33
```

Finalmente puedes comprobar que no son iguales mediante:

```
division_con_decimales == menos_decimales
```

**Resultado**

```
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Una forma elegante y sencilla de hacerlo es con `math.trunc`

```
import math

def truncate(numero, cifras):
    posiciones = pow(10.0, cifras)
    return math.trunc(posiciones * numero) / posiciones

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numero = 10/3.0
    cifras = 3
    truncate(numero, cifras)
```

Y al ejecutarlo arroja un valor de la forma.

```
...
3.333
```

Lo que hace el truco es que en `posiciones*numero` el numero que ingresaste se recorre la cantidad de cifras hacía la derecha, `math.trunc` elimina los dígitos sobrantes de la derecha y luego, al dividir entre `posiciones`, se recorren los mismos dígitos que se recorrieron previamente a la derecha pero ahora hacía la izquierda.

Es decir.

Si ingresaste 5.55555 y quieres tres cifras, primero se multiplica 5.55555*10^3, entonces resulta 5555.55. `math.trunc` obtiene únicamente el 5555 y luego eso se divide entre 10^3, por lo que ahora 5555/10^3 = 5.555

Answer (score 2):

Vi que todos usan el `.format()` pero me pareció curioso que ninguno use `round()`

Ejemplo

```
División = 10/3

print(round(división,2)
```

**formula**

```
round(variable, numero de dígitos que queremos mostrar)
```

Ese código te mostraría el resultado de la división con dos decímales.

Comment: Muy bien! Pero que pasa si quieres mostrar 20 decimales como detalló el autor de la pregunta?  Ronda redondea un decimal, pero no te muestra los decimales según quieras. Intenta `round(10/3,20)` y verás que obtienes solo 16 decimales

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 3.3333333333333335
print(float("{0:.3f}".format(x)))
# output: 3.333
y = float("{0:.3f}".format(x))
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi ganes tu primera medalla!.tambien te invito a que leas [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), Describe que es lo que haces ya que puede haber gente que no entienda por que recien estan empezando, dicho eso edita tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma sería así:

```
print(f"{10/3:.3f}")
```

el resultado sería:
3.333