# ¿Cómo le puedo indicar a python cuantos decimales quiero que muestre?

Tags: python

Por ejemplo, tengo las siguientes líneas de código:

```
# Input / Declaración de variables
numero_empleado = int(input())
horas_trabajadas = int(input())
salario_por_hora = float(input())

# Ecuación
salario = horas_trabajadas * salario_por_hora

# Output
print(f"NUMBER = {numero_empleado}")
print(f"SALARY = ${salario}))
```

¿Cómo indico que deseo que la variable flotante "salario" salga con X cantidad de decimales? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Limitar dígitos en un número periódico en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/236945/limitar-d%c3%adgitos-en-un-n%c3%bamero-peri%c3%b3dico-en-python)

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente:

```
print(f"SALARY = ${salario:.2f}))
```

el 2 representa los decimales deseados

Comment: Hay más de una manera. Sería útil que las mencionaras todas.

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera de resolverlo sería la siguiente:

```
    redondeo = round(salario, 2)
    print(redondeo)
```

Answer (score 0):

> > > **¿Cómo le puedo indicar a python cuantos decimales quiero que muestre?**

El `round()` incorporado funciona bien en Python 2.7 o posterior.

**Ejemplo:**

```
>>> round(14.22222223, 2)
14.22
```

o si no esto.

Siento que el enfoque más simple es usar la función format().

**Por ejemplo:**

```
a = 13.949999999999999
format(a, '.2f')

13.95
```

Esto produce un número flotante como una cadena redondeada a dos puntos decimales.

Eso si deberás adaptarlo a tu código , lo mio es un ejemplo simplemente